# Rails: remove the label from a simple_form_for collection association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-form-for, simple-form-for

I am trying to remove the label that is auto included when we use '.association' of the simple_form_for. But, regardless of what I do, the title and its `<hr>` continue to be displayed.

I tried:

```
<%= f.association :attr_vals, collection: attr.attr_vals, 
    as: :check_boxes, wrapper: false, label: false %>
```

and

```
<%= f.association :attr_vals, collection: attr.attr_vals, 
    as: :check_boxes, wrapper: false, label: "" %>
```

But it keeps showing :/

What can I do to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<%= f.association :attr_vals, collection: attr.attr_vals, 
    as: :check_boxes, wrapper: false, label_method: "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`label: false` seems to work, for example handling an enum collection

```
    <%= form.association :functions,
                          collection: functions.map { |f| [Function.functions.key(f)&.humanize, f] }, 
                          as: :check_boxes, 
                          label: false %>
```